# Inline CSS in react

Tags: css, reactjs, inline

```
{
       <div style={{color: 'red', padding-left: '30px',padding-top: '10px' }}>
        errorMessage
       </div>
}
```

JSX expressions must have one parent element

no error expected when using the inline css

Comment: The error is in the code wrapping `{}`. Please show whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div element must be wrapped with `React Fragment` or another `jsx element`, not `{}`. Like this;

```js
<>
  <div style={{color: 'red', padding-left: '30px',padding-top: '10px' }}>
     errorMessage
  </div>
</>
```

or

```js
<React.Fragment>
  <div style={{color: 'red', padding-left: '30px',padding-top: '10px' }}>
     errorMessage
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

or

```js
<div>
  <div style={{color: 'red', padding-left: '30px',padding-top: '10px' }}>
     errorMessage
  </div>
</div>
```